# Where can I store non-localizable fixed strings in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, constants

I have some url templates that I use in my app - they are not localizable strings, so config/locales/en.yml does not seem like the best place for them - where do I store these? For example, "http://www.example.com/apps?id=" is one such string.

I know there are several approaches possible (a constants file in the lib folder, or using rails configuration in rails4, or some config gem like [configatron](https://github.com/markbates/configatron)), but what is the'right' way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is "a right way" - the new 'x' configuration option system in Rails 4 seems to be the most "Railsy" solution out there.

I personally think it is totally okay to have a GlobalConstants module defined in an initializer or a file in the lib directory. Put all your global constants in there and be diligent about using them throughout your app where needed.

For projects where there's a mix and match of i18n strings I like having a "base" i18n file and then using the override system to create a sort of inheritance chain between the i18n files. That's not always the appropriate solution but I've had it work out quite well a few times.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

As you said there are many solutions and it dependence on usage.

You can store them in environment variables.
dotenv gem help you handle it easier:

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv